# Invalid object name request error occurs upon trying to query local SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, knex.js

I have successfully connected to a production SQL Server database and queried it using knex. I then restored that database locally using Docker and SQL Operations Studio on macOS (following [this walkthrough](https://database.guide/how-to-restore-a-sql-server-database-on-a-mac-using-sql-operations-studio/)). I was able to connect to it and query it from within SQLOPS. I am now attempting to connect to and query that local database programmatically instead of the production database. I updated the configuration to fill in the relevant info for the locally hosted database but I believe it's not entirely correct as I am receiving the following error:

> RequestError: select top (@p0) * from [OurTableName] where [SomeID] = @p1 - Invalid object name 'OurTableName'.

Researching that error revealed it could be a configuration issue. Here is my config object:

```
{
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost',
    port: 1433,
    options: {
      encrypt: false,
      database: 'ourdbname',
    },
  },
  pool: {
    min: 2,
    max: 10,
  },
}
```

Do you see where the issue lies? Is there anything else I would need to do within SQLOPS before I would be able to connect to it programmatically?

Comment: are you sure "OurTableName" exists in "OurDBName" ? Maybe do a "select [name] from sys.Tables" to see what you have in OurDbName database.

Comment: @CetinBasoz that query gives these results: ```[ { name: 'spt_fallback_db' },
  { name: 'spt_fallback_dev' },
  { name: 'spt_fallback_usg' },
  { name: 'spt_monitor' },
  { name: 'MSreplication_options' } ]```

Comment: Those are master database tables. You are connected to wrong database then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through Knex's own SQL Server config file [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/test/knexfile.js#L116), their config is formatted differently. Not sure where your config came from, but give this a shot:

```
{
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: testConfig.mssql || {
      user: 'sa',
      password: 'S0meVeryHardPassword',
      server: 'localhost',
      database: 'knex_test',
    },
    pool: pool,
    migrations: migrations,
    seeds: seeds,
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, moving the database out of options, thank you! And welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

This is frequently a problem with which database you are connected to, versus which database holds the table. An `'sa'` login defaults to the `master` database. Try using this type of request:

```
select top (@p0) * 
from [OurDBName].[dbo].[OurTableName] 
where [SomeID] = @p1
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify that in the config? My query is built with knex like so `const obj = await knex('OurTableName').where({SomeID: '1'}).first();` so it's not a raw query like that.

Comment: Can confirm this is the problem! That raw query works. Any ideas on how to configure it to fully qualify that with the config?

Comment: I haven't worked with Knex before, but try using `const obj = await knex('OurDBName.dbo.OurTableName').where({SomeID: '1'}).first();`

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem its because *"default_database_name"* was set to the wrong DB:

First **check** what "default_database_name" is, execute following query:

```
SELECT sp.name , sp.default_database_name FROM sys.server_principals
 sp WHERE sp.name = SUSER_SNAME();
```

If this is indeed set to the wrong DB Name, you can **change** it like this:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = TheRightDbName;`
```

Now the right DB is set and the object can be found like usual.